# How to Populate A grid View Properly?

Tags: sql, asp.net

SELECT txnid, snum, txndate, status FROM detail WHERE (txnid = @txnid)

Label2.Text = txnid.ToString();

i want to populate my grid view with the following , i have set the parameters in a sqldatasource , that @txnid = label2.text , when i test query , the type is Int32? then it populates. but when i run the program it does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

add these lines of code:

```
Gridview1.datasource = sqldatasource;
Gridview1.databind();
```